# onBackpressed isn't working with listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-tabactivity

I am working on android Version 8 and my emulator 2.2 
I have tabview with Activity group, and multi childs and they are all listview but one is Activity 
the onbackPressed method is not working for the List Activity 
I have searcged and i found this code

```
@Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && CatalogGroup.group != null) {
       CatalogGroup.group.popView();
       return true;
   }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

the problem is popView() is undefined in the type Group Activity 
and this is my Code

```
public class TabsGroup extends ActivityGroup {
public static TabsGroup group;
// additional Code
}
```

and this is the back Code

```
public void back() {
    if(history.size() > 0) {
        history.remove(history.size()-1);
        if (history.size() > 0)
            setContentView(history.get(history.size()-1));
    }else {
        finish();
    }
}

   public void onBackPressed() {
   CatalogGroup.group.back();
    return;
}
```

How could I make the back button works for the ListView ?

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `onKeyDown` yourself like:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // Your stuff
    } else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "//Your stuff" ??!